# Pandas df.loc[] gives SyntaxError when both row and column indexers are given inside double square brackets. Why?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make `.loc[]` return a data frame when given a row indexer and a column indexer. Below is the code that is erroring out.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> user_data = {
...     'name': ['Ananth', 'John', 'Wong', 'Souza', 'Jane'],
...     'age': [21, 27, 24, 33, 19],
...     'skill': ['data science', 'machine learning', 'front end designing', 'UI and UX', '3D modelling'],
...     'country': ['Sri Lanka', 'United Kingdom', 'China', 'Netherlands', 'USA'],
...     'is_disabled': [True, False, False, False, True]
...     }
>>> dfuser = pd.DataFrame(user_data)
>>> dfuser.index.tolist()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> dfuser.loc[:, 'name']
0    Ananth
1      John
2      Wong
3     Souza
4      Jane
Name: name, dtype: object
>>> dfuser.loc[[:, 'name']]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    dfuser.loc[[:, 'name']]
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`.loc` is returning a data frame when given a row index inside double square brackets. But why isn't it doing the same when both row and column indexes are passed?

---

**Edit:**

My expected output (of the errored line) is to be the same as `dfuser[['name']]`.

```py
>>> dfuser.loc[[:, 'name']]  # this is the code that gives me error, but I want the output to look like below.
     name
0  Ananth
1    John
2    Wong
3   Souza
4    Jane
>>> dfuser[['name']]
     name
0  Ananth
1    John
2    Wong
3   Souza
4    Jane
>>> type(dfuser[['name']])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: How looks expectd output?

Comment: @jezrael I have added the expected output in the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

For get column `name` to one column `DataFrame` add `[]` for column, because `:` is for select all rows here:

```
print (dfuser.loc[:, ['name']])
     name
0  Ananth
1    John
2    Wong
3   Souza
4    Jane
```

---

```
idx = [1,2]
print (dfuser.loc[idx, ['name']])
   name
1  John
2  Wong
```